# Pass data between worker threads in node js

Tags: node.js, worker-thread

I have a nodejs application where I need to use a worker thread.
The worker thread gets a message from the main thread. The message is sent inside a function in a class.
I need to pass the instance of the class to the worker but I can't figure out how.
I understand the data needs to be passed inside a sharedArrayBuffer but how do I convert an instance of a class to a sharedArrayBuffer?

this is the postMessage code:

```
            worker.postMessage({
                db_manager: this
            });
```

"this" is my instance.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not create the class instance inside the worker?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Marc I need the instance that is created in the main thread because the worker needs to update data there.

Comment: Thats not possible, you cant serialize a class instance.